# In general, is there a there a way to access a Child class from another child class when they both share the same parent class?

Tags: c++, class, parent-child

So let's consider we have a Parent class

```
class Parent
{
};
```

I have then two child class

```
class Child1 : public Parent
{
 void AccessFunction();
}
```

and

```
class Child2 : public Parent
{
void FunctionBeingAccessed();
}
```

where

```
void Child1::AccessFunction()
{
  FunctionBeingAccessed();
}
```

Is it possible?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers !

So the reason i am asking this is because i have a third class GrandChild, And i was searching for a way to Make it a Child of **ALL** the Child classes of the Parent Class, despite them being different.

Is there a way to do so?

EDIT2:

Better explanation of my problem.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VV0y.png)

So i have a player, item and level class who are childs of the 3dmodel class. And i would like to make the collision class, a child of them. So do i need to use virtual inheritance

Comment: The easy answer: Nope. The long answer: It's complicated, and of course there are ways to do it that you generally shouldn't do.

Comment: `FunctionBeingAccessed()` needs to be called on an instance of class `Child2`, unless you declare it `static`, in which case you would need to call it like `Child2::FunctionBeingAccessed()`

Comment: For your GrandChild class, you may want to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: RE: Your edit. Multiple inheritance and as Carlton said, virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Carlton : So if i wrote in Child2 static `static void FunctionBeingAccessed()`, i can call it in Child1 without using `Child2::` ?       Also thx both of you ( AndyG, Carlton) i ll look into virtual inheritance. I ll also add a picture (if i can) to show a precise situation fo my problem

Comment: No, you need to call the static method with the `Child2::` identifier, otherwise the compiler will not know where to look for `FunctionBeingAccessed()`.

Comment: @glaziko usually when something seems really complicated then most likely implies a bad design choice

Comment: Yeah i know. If the collision is put in the model class. all this is not needed. but i am stuck with this composition for academic reasons (for instance bad design that can't be changed now) :(

Comment: Should an object of type Collision have all the functionality of a Level, Player, and Item?  That's what will happen if you inherit from all three of those classes.  I don't know what your design is exactly, but this seems like a very roundabout way of implementing it.

Comment: Alright thank you all for you answer ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is possible, but you have to set the protection level of `FunctionBeingAccessed();` to **public**. The default protection level for classes is **private**, and therefore your code won't work.

Change `void FunctionBeingAccessed();` to this:

```
class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
void FunctionBeingAccessed();
}
```

That should work.

Comment: It is I who should apologize. You were technically correct about public/private, but in my opinion you are still missing the point of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `Child1` a friend of `Child2`, then objects of type `Child1` can access private/protected methods of `Child2`.